# simple jQuery accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm trying to write simple accordion, im not sure what I'm missing here.
It Div : aquashow needs to be hidden when the page loads, and when user click on the button it needs to be show/hide

```js
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    
$(function() {
    $('#aquashow').hide();

    $("#aqua").click(function(e) {
        $("#aquashow").toggle();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <a href="#" class="button button__secondary icon-collapse" id="aqua">Aquatics</a>
        </p>
        <div id="aquashow">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis omnis qui quidem repudiandae illum, aut delectus quas. Minus quibusdam asperiores sed est voluptatibus natus, sint aliquam voluptate amet? Neque, esse!</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Test 1</li>
                <li>Test 2</li>
                <li>Test 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/bw32aeoh/).  In what way is the code not working as expected for you?

Comment: It seems working fine. If you want to simulate the original accordion animation then show/hide is not enough. You may try `slideToggle()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work according to @David's link, but wasnt on my computer. :-(..

I have re did the code using slideToggle() as mentioned by @Ali and it started working. I'm not sure why the previouse one wasnt working. But thanks for your feedback.